# how to re-run test failed suites in robotframework using maven and JAVA

Tags: java, maven, robotframework

After running a test pack, is there any way I can run failed test suites only in Robot Framework for Java with maven?.

I know there is an option to re-run failed test cases but not for test suits.

Comment: What is the rational for rerunning entire test suites instead of test cases? Ideally a test case should be entirely standalone and not depend on the state of a previous test case(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For tests

http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/run-mojo.html#runFailed

- For suits

This feature doesn't exist.

But you can do it with IntelliJ IDEA.
For example, you ran unit tests and one test failed.
You can click on the button - "Rerun Failed Tests".

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

I hope, it helps you!

Comment: How can do with Intellj IDEA?